# How to wait for Compact Repair - Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Have a VBA Module in Access 2007 which performs similar actions in a For loop.
At the end of every loop I wish to compact and repair the current database before proceeding to the next iteration.

Reason : In every iteration I create , use for calculation and delete a table.
The size should remain under control.

Using SendKeys , I cannot compact and repair - if calling the module from a Form Button.
Any trick to ensure that the SendKey works fine and the Module continues onto the next iteration flawlessly. Some idea to control Form loading / Module execution / Checking Status etc. 
End Purpose being to wait just long enough till the Compacting is done and then move on. Also how to safely ensure that SendKeys / (suggest alternate) for compacting works fine.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access: how to compact current database in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460129/ms-access-how-to-compact-current-database-in-vba)

Comment: That other question is similar in that it also deals with compact.  However, this question asks about compact within a `For` loop ... compacting the current database multiple times, which means it would have to preserve state of the loop before and after compact.  That's a whole nother level of complexity beyond a simple compact.

Comment: MS Access remains at a large size for a reason - it's claimed some disk space that it knows it can use. I'm not sure what the point of shrinking is if your next piece of code just expands it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"... in a For loop. At the end of every loop I wish to compact and repair the current database before proceeding to the next iteration."*

Consider what actually happens when you compact the current database.  Access first creates a compacted version of the current database as a *new* db file.  Then it deletes the old db file, renames the new file to the old name, and finally opens the new db file.

So if your code attempted compact each cycle through a `For` loop ... when Access then opens the compacted db file ... how would it know you wanted it to continue in that `For` loop?

If you truly want to do something like that, you will have to store a value to record which was the last iteration of the `For` loop.  Then create an *autoexec* macro to retrieve that value at database open, and enter the `For` loop at the appropriate cycle.  And then decide whether you really want that all to happen every time the database is opened.

However that seems like too much effort to me.  It should be simpler to use another db file to hold your volatile data.  Then from code in the *current* database you can use [DBEngine.CompactDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220986%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to compact the external db file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing that much compact & repair, then I would split the DB into a front-end and a back-end. All your tables will be on the back-end. Splitting the DB is pretty standard for any regular Access programmer anyway.

Then when you want, use the Shell command to open the back-end DB with the **/compact** switch. This will open it, do a compact & repair, and then close it.

So, your code will be something like this:

```
Ret = Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE /compact c:\MyFolder\MyDB.accdb")
```

If you need to wait for it to finish, then use the **WScript.Shell** command instead.

Good Luck

Comment: An alternative might be `DBEngine.CompactDatabase "C:\__tmp\tempDB.accdb", "C:\__tmp\newTempDB.accdb"`, which will happen in the current Access instance (and will wait).

Comment: Haven't used that method. Can it be compacted into the same DB, or does it require a new DB?

Comment: The destination database must not already exist when using `DBEngine.CompactDatabase` so yes, it insists on making a new database file.

Comment: Good to know if I need to backup a DB, but I don't think it would solve the OPs need.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot compact and repair the current database in a loop of any kind.**  You could compact and repair an external database in a loop, or you could compact the current database on close.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131820/temp-table-in-access-manage-size) (which is quite similar), but for the sake of helping others I have published a simple utility function that helps you restart and compact the current database:

- [Restarting and compacting an MSAccess database programmatically](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/ms-access-restarting-the-database-programmatically/)

To ensure that you continue the proper iteration after you restart:

- save the state of your operation (for instance the loop count) in a `LocalSettings` table (for instance) in your database.
- Restart.
- Use an `autoexec` macro to launch the function that does your work: it should load the operation/loop count from the `LocalSettings` table and carry-on.

Another solution is to modify the restart function to pass a custom command line argument to the Access application that you can check when the app restarts.
You can easily check for command line arguments, see the VBA [Command function](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080205899&lcid=2057&NS=MSACCESS%2EDEV&Version=14&tl=2&CTT=4).